# SQL Query with join on non-unique Entries

Tags: sql, join

I have problems with two tables I need to join.

```
Table1

Order_id              Item_Revenue            Item_id
1                     30 €                    22222222
1                     20 €                    11111111
1                     10 €                    33333333
2                     5 €                     55555555

Table2

package_id           Order_id                 shipping_costs
456                  1                        1 €
567                  1                        2 €
789                  1                        3 €
999                  2                        2 €
```

The Output I need: I want to show the Item Revenue and the Shipping costs per Order_Id

```
Order_ID          count(item_id)      sum(item_revenue)  sum(shipping_costs)
1                 3                   60 €                6 €
2                 1                   5 €                 2 €
```

My first try was:

```
Select
sum(t1.item_revenue),
count(t1.item_id),
sum(t2.shipping_costs),
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
group by t1.order_id
```

But it does not work because order_id is not unique.

Please look at my example:

I would be so lucky if somebody could help me.

Comment: Do you want order 2 and 3 in the result?

Comment: yes. I edited my example to make it more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need inner join

```
    Select order_id,count( distinct item_id),
    sum(item_revenue),
    sum(shipping_costs)
    from table1
    join table2 on table1.order_id = table2.order_id
    group by order_id
```

Comment: Does this work, if both tables have multiple entries for order_id?

Comment: yes I tried! Normally I have 500.000 Order_id's in my database. But when I use the inner join, the output only has 5 order_ids.

Comment: @ML84 inner join will return only those orderid which are available in both tables

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with alias and missing commas.
in the `GROUP BY` you used "`order_id`" but you need to define the field related with Table1 or Table2.
Also, for alias. Don't start with number like 1,2. you can get error message.

**EDIT** (Table2 in SubQuery):

```
Select
    T1.order_id
    ,count(1) ItemCount
    ,sum(item_revenue) ItemRevenue
    ,sum(shipping_costs) ShippingCost
from table1 T1
INNER join (SELECT Order_id
                  ,SUM(shipping_costs) shipping_costs  
            FROM Table2
            GROUP BY Order_id) T2 on T1.order_id = T2.order_id
group by T1.order_id
```

Comment: The alias and missing commas are allright, sorry, i just forgot to put them into my sample data. my question is how to set up the query, because a left join did not work.

Comment: @ML84 Which sql you using?

Comment: Workbench for Amazon Redshift

Comment: @ML84 . I have changed the query with using subquery.  I think this is what you want.

Comment: Ok, I tried:

SELECT 
table1.order_id,
sum(table1.item_revenue) as Item_revenue,
count (table1.item_id),
shipping_costs,
FROM table1
inner join (select table2.order_id, 
         sum(table2.shipping_costs)as shipping_costs 
         from table2  
         group by table2.order_id)
         on table2.order_id = table1.order_id
group by table1.order_id;

But the error message is ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "FROM"

Comment: @ML84 delete last comma before FROM

Comment: @ML84 after you delete it you will get another error message about your sub-query. You need to put alias to your sub-query: add "Table2" before "ON" . And  you need to add shipping_costs to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps and assuming you are using Oracle SQL

```
select table1.Order_id
sum(table1.item_revenue)
count(table1.item_id)
sum(table2.shipping_costs)
from
(
  select Order_id,Item_Revenue,Item_id, row_number() over (partition by Order_id order by Item_id) as man_id
  from table 1
)
table1
left join
(
  select package_id,Order_id,shipping_costs, row_number() over (partition by Order_id order by package_id) as man_id
  from table 2
)
table2
on table1.order_id = table2.order_id
and table1.man_id = table2.man_id
group by table1.order_id
```

Comment: item_id in table1 and package_id in table2 are not the same.

Comment: Yes, I used item_id in table1 and package_id in table2 just to order and I have not joined them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select order_id , count(item_id), sum(item_revenue) , sum(shipping_costs)
```

from table1, table2
where table1.orderid=table2.order_id
group by order_id

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the two tables *before* joining.  Then `join` using a `full join` so you get all orders in both tables:

```
select coalesce(t1.order_id, t2.order_id) as order_id,  -- include the order_id
       t1_revenue, t1_count,
       shipping_costs
from (select t1.order_id, sum(t1.item_revenue) as t1_revenue, count(*) as t1_count
      from table1 t1
      group by t1.order_id
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.order_id, t2.shipping_costs as shipping_costs
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.order_id
     ) t2
     on t1.order_id = t2.order_id;
```

If your database doesn't support `full join`, then use `left join`.  Presumably, orders in `table2` are also in `table1`.